# Why use Euler Angles

Tags: rotations

I am having trouble understanding why Euler Angles are used to rotate objects at all. Why parent the axes of rotations and have them depend on each other and change orientation when the parent changes?

If I want to rotate an object, can't I just use the fixed global coordinate system to do this? In other words, do they solve a real problem, make rotations easier?

This is essentially asking what's the pros/cons of intrinsic vs extrinsic rotations?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're wondering about **intrinsic** rotations vs **extrinsic** rotations?

Comment: Gimbal's use Euler angles and have been used for for millennia and has many modern applications as well.

Comment: @MattiP. looked that up, yes I think that they are equivalent after all. Question is what's the advantage of one over the other. Updated my post